# How to send USB control transaction on nonzero endpoint (libusb)?

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, microcontroller, device-driver, libusb

I'm writing code to learn about the USB peripheral on a Freescale Kinetis microcontroller.  I've managed to get through enumeration on a Linux host, and I can send & receive packets using vendor-custom codes on EP0, interacting with a libusb test program.

It looks like I can configure additional control endpoints (non-zero endpoint numbers) on the microcontroller, but I don't see a way to make libusb send / receive control transfers to those endpoints.  (`libusb_control_transfer` doesn't require an endpoint number, though `libusb_bulk_transfer` and `libusb_interrupt_transfer` do.)

Are non-zero control endpoints so uncommon or unnecessary that it's not worth bothering with them?  Is there some way to get libusb to execute control transactions to non-zero endpoints?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way to get libusb to execute control transactions to non-zero endpoints?

You can try to modify the `endpoint` field in the `libusb_transfer` structure of the asynchronous I/O API.

But it would surprise me if your microcontroller could actually support non-zero control endpoint(s) - not that many do.

In practise you would rather use either interrupt or bulk endpoints. Both have less overhead - allowing higher throughput with bulk transfers (see for example USB 2.0 SPEC Table 5-2 vs. Table 5-9).

Comment: Thanks...I was using the synchronous parts of libusb, so I copied and modified the send_control function to plug a different endpoint into the async structure that it builds on.  No joy, but I don't have a protocol analzyer to tell whether there's a packet going out at all.  (It wouldn't be surprising for the microcontroller documentation to be wrong, either.)  Anyway, I'll try one of the other types of endpoints and see what happens.