# USB control message to endpoint 0x80 in libusb-1?

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, device-driver, libusb

USB soundcard Creative X-Fi switches from USB1.1 to USB2.0 when its proprietary windows driver is used, allowing faster samplerates in its USB2 configuration. A capture of USB packets by wireshark shows several commands are sent by the proprietary driver just before the device disconnects and re-connects at USB2. I am trying to replay the commands to the device in linux, to be able to add the same feature to the existing linux usb-audio driver.

I want to use python, presumably the libusb1 wrapper around libusb-1 library. The captured packet shows the driver sends usb control request to endpoint 0x80 with wIndex 0. Please is there a way to format and send such a packet with libusb-1? I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39343813/15717902 but do not know if it still holds.

The captured packet:

```
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 3.5.0]
    USBPcap pseudoheader length: 28
    IRP ID: 0xfffffa8009ebd3e0
    IRP USBD_STATUS: USBD_STATUS_SUCCESS (0x00000000)
    URB Function: URB_FUNCTION_VENDOR_OTHER (0x0020)
    IRP information: 0x00, Direction: FDO -> PDO
    URB bus id: 3
    Device address: 5
    Endpoint: 0x80, Direction: IN
    URB transfer type: URB_CONTROL (0x02)
    Packet Data Length: 8
    [Response in: 20]
    Control transfer stage: Setup (0)
    [bInterfaceClass: Unknown (0xffff)]
Setup Data
    bmRequestType: 0xc3
    bRequest: 42
    wValue: 0x0000
    wIndex: 0 (0x0000)
    wLength: 2
```

Comment: I highly recommend to drop a message to Linux-usb@ and Alsa-devel@ mailing lists with Cc to Takashi Iwai, Ruslan Bilovol, and Alan Stern.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did so a few weeks ago https://mailman.alsa-project.org/pipermail/alsa-devel/2021-May/184317.html :-) I am afraid I have to figure out the correct sequence on my own first and then I can ask them for help with integration into the snd-usb-audio driver. That's why I am looking at user-space USB options.